# Aligning multiple vetices while maintaining mesh shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges

So I have the below mesh in wireframe and I'm looking from it's right side. What is the easiest way to align these edges like the 2 (or rather 4) on the far right? (edit: edges in red are actually 4 edges a certain width apart, they just look like a single edge because they're aligned when viewing from the side)

I've tried playing around with scaling on the y axis but this will only work doing 2 vertices at a time otherwise the shape of the mesh is lost. Surely there's a more efficient way of doing this and I'm just missing it.

I've also tried selecting the edges and using edge slide + Ctrl to snap to a vertex but the lines also aren't the same shape which I gather is likely my own fault as I'm still getting the hang of shaping meshes still but this may make this a little awkward to do so I'm guessing scaling vertices one at a time may be my best option.

[image]

Comment: "to align these edges like the 2 (or rather 4) on the far right", perhaps it's just me but I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: Sorry should've highlighted that first. The edges in red are actually 4 edges a certain width apart, they just look like a single edge because they're aligned when viewing from the side. 

As you can see there's another 4 edges like this (2 pairs) of a similar shape yet they're not overlapping from the side and aren't exactly the same shape, I'm not sure is there a way to fix this other than scaling each vertex pair along the Y axis.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you could try remove doubles (Merge by Distance in 2.80) and set a big enough distance that it captures the vertices you are cleaning up.

Comment: Didn't realise that was a thing, sounds very useful but I don't think it'd work for me as it'd merge into a single vertex, basically I'd need to pair up the vertices that aren't aligned and give them the same Y and Z value but keep them X distance apart, seems like this needs to be done one vertex pair at a time tho which is what I ended up doing.

Thanks for your reply tho, still taught me about merging doubles by a certain distance so always good to learn something new!